# WPF: How to call a method similar to ICommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

This might seems a silly question, but I'm in a learning curve so asking this.
In fact, I'm trying to find an alternative to a previous unresolved question:
[WPF: How to make Calls to Dispatcher.Invoke() Synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839155/wpf-how-to-make-calls-to-dispatcher-invoke-synchronous)

In MVVM Application, we define ICommand for a Button's Command Binding, which may call another method, load another ViewModel or execute some instructions etc. 
**Update with code:**
Here is my ICommand, binding to button, which will load the ViewModel to show EndView:

```
  public ICommand EndCommand => new RelayCommand(p =>
    {
        WixBootstrapperData.CurrentViewModel = new EndViewModel(WixBootstrapperData);

    });
```

But when I tried to load same ViewModel from another method, it did the loading, but never showed the EndView, and skipped to other instructions till the end of method, which is in fact end of application itself. Here is the snippet:

BootstrapperApplication.ApplyComplete += (sender, e) =>
       {

```
       WixBootstrapperData.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           if (e.Restart == ApplyRestart.RestartRequired)
           {
               //This would be loaded, but never showed the related View and skipped to next instruction
               WixBootstrapperData.CurrentViewModel = new EndViewModel(WixBootstrapperData); 

           }
           //However, This would be loaded and related View would also be displayed
           WixBootstrapperData.CurrentViewModel = new FinishViewModel(WixBootstrapperData);
       }
       ));
   }
```

Can we call same ICommand from another Method to get same behavior? Or some alternative way?

Does defining an event and subscribing to that would give same behavior from within a method execution?

Comment: Is it possible you could post the code for your `ICommand` property (and possibly where you're assigning the delegate for it) in your ViewModel, please? I've added an answer below - but I don't want to be too assumptive with what type you're using. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. That's cool, I just wanted to see if you were using the `RelayCommand` as your command types - have a look at my answer below; hopefully it helps :)

Comment: Let's say `if (e.Restart == ApplyRestart.RestartRequired)` is true.  What happens?  `CurrentViewModel = EndViewModel`.  But then the method continues to execute, and now `CurrentViewModel = FinishViewModel`.  I think you need an `else` inbetween the close of the `if` and the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a command from within another method.

First, it is advised to check if the command *can* be executed, by using `.CanExecute()` - which returns a `bool`

If you can indeed execute the commnad, then you can call `.Execute()` on that command.

---

**Example:**

Let's say your `ICommand` is a `RelayCommand`, and called `MyCommand`.

Let's say you want to call it from `SomeOtherMethod()`:

```
public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    if (MyCommand.CanExecute())
    {
        MyCommand.Execute();
    }
}
```

The same methods are available if you're using a `DelegateCommand`, as well - I use these using Prism.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks @FarrukhWaheed - please let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Yes, it was executed without any problems, but behavior was same. It again didn't showed the View i.e. With and without MyCommand.Execute(this) it never showed the EndView, but FinishView.